# Limit of unconditionally convergent series is independent of order of summation in a general (real) normed vector space.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, analysis, convergence-divergence

I am trying to show that if $\sum{x_n}$ converges unconditionally then $\sum{x_n}=\sum{x_{\sigma(n)}}$ for any bijection $\sigma$ of $\mathbb N$. I have shown this when the vector space is $\mathbb R$ by proving the following claims in order:

1. If $(x_n)\geq{0}$, $\sum{x_n}<\infty$ then the sum is unconditionally convergent.
2. Unconditional convergence $\implies$ absolute convergence.
3. Unconditional convergence implies result (first show true if all summands are non-negative then extend to the general case by splitting into the positive and negative sums using (1) and (2)).

However these claims relied heavily on the ordering or the reals and I can't see how to generalise this to any normed space.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: What's the _definition_  of unconditional convergence here? I ask because I would have said that the definition was exactly what you say you want to prove. (Tried looking it up; Wikipedia agrees: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unconditional_convergence)

Comment: Oh yes I saw that...my definition is just that the sum of any permutations converges, but not necessarily to the same limit. The wikipedia definition did make me question whether it was actually true from that definition but it was set as an exercise in some notes and I'm fairly certain my proof was correct over $\mathbb R$!

Comment: If you have two permutations of $\mathbb{N}$ such that $$\sum x_{\sigma(n)} = A \neq B = \sum x_{\tau(n)}\,,$$ then you can "combine" them to get a permutation such that $\sum x_{\eta(n)}$ doesn't converge at all, having subsequences of partial sums converging to $A$ and to $B$ respectively.

Comment: @DanielFischer Could you please elaborate on this idea or give reference? I know it can be done that way but I can't recall the details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In case I'm not the only one who thought this was just the *definition* of unconditional convergence: It appears that here we're saying a series converges unconditionally if any permutation converges, although perhaps to a different sum.

Of course the result for finite-dimensional $V$ is immediate from the result for $V=\Bbb R$: Wlog $V=\Bbb R^d$; apply the one-dimensional result in each coordinate.

That may serve to motivate the proof in general. Sayy $\Lambda$ is a continuous linear functional on $V$. Then $$\Lambda \sum x_n=\sum\Lambda x_n=\sum\Lambda x_{\sigma(n)}=\Lambda\sum x_{\sigma(n)}.$$The Hahn-Banach theorem shows that the continuous linear functionals on $V$  separate points, hence qed.

Comment: this is such a neat solution, thank you!